# Starcraft Display Issues

Tags: starcraft

I installed Starcraft Broodwars for my grandson on my desktop. I have Windows 7.  On the screen, the far left has about two inches of black screen, which cuts off the far right of the game display.  I installed it on a laptop without this issue.  Any ideas on how a non-gaming grandma can fix this desktop issue?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a screenshot of this issue, would you?

Comment: @Frank: I have a vague suspicion it would look perfect with a screenshot, and this is a videocard/monitor communication issue.  As to what to _do_, I have no idea though.  Uninstall/reinstall/update video drivers?

Comment: Broodwars is pretty old, so this could be an age issue. On Windows 7, it may need to be run in compatibility mode, with a different resolution, and/or with a different color depth.

Comment: How do I take a screen shot, then how do I post it here?  Claire (aka non-gaming Grandma)

Comment: I did ALT + PRINT SCREEN, then pasted into Word, but the image produced did not resemble the display.    Claire

Comment: murgatroid99, I had tried your suggestion already without success.

Comment: @Claire: Unrelated, you can go here (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/edit/108867) to change your display name from "user108867".

Answer (score 1):

While this question is already quite old and this answer is probably pointless, this sounds like a monitor calibration issue.

This can usually be resolved in 3 ways. Unfortunately, Brood War doesn't support the 2nd and 3rd way:

1. Use the buttons on the actual monitor to move the image on the screen to the left.
2. Change the display resolution of the game. Unfortunately this game doesn't support changing the display resolution out of the box: 
   [How can I change the screen resolution?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103933/how-can-i-change-the-screen-resolution)
3. Run the game in windowed mode. Unfortunately this game doesn't support windowed mode out of the box: [Is it possible to run Starcraft in windowed mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114838/is-it-possible-to-run-starcraft-in-windowed-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I never stand at this problem before, hopefully you could use this to try to resolve your Starcraft problem http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-fix-Starcrafts-bad-colors/ or maybe you could use Chaos Launcher to play Starcraft in windowed mode http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/closed-threads/72621-play-starcraft-in-windowed-mode. I did use ChaosLauncher before in Windows 7 and for me it worked well. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try to Alt-Tab out of the game. When you come to the desktop you can click on the game in the taskbar to bring it up again, this might fix the issue.

IF you still have the issue, try running the game in "Window" mode instead of full-screen mode. When you have it in a window, you can press Alt+Enter to make the window go full screen which should also fix the issue.

Comment: Alt+Enter does not cause SC to switch to window mode. You need third party programs, like xenotron's w-mode.